# Acessar as API do Mercado Livre pelo Delphi XE5

Tags: json, delphi

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação em Delphi para integrar o ERP ao Mercado Livre,  e ao utilizar o REST Debugger (para teste) esta me retornando uma HTML e não Json, alguém já passou por isso?

Se utilizar o Postman retorna o Json correto, contudo pelo Delphi ou o REST Debugger só retorna o HTML.

Código utilizado:

```
RESTClient.Accept        := 'application/json'; 
RESTClient.BaseURL       := 'api.mercadolibre.com/currencies?id=BRL';
RESTClient.AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8'; 
RESTClient.ContentType   := 'application/json';
RESTRequest.Method       := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;   
RESTRequest.Execute;
```

Deveria retornar

```
{ "id": "BRL", "symbol": "R$", "description": "Real", "decimal_places": 2}
```

Retorna

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--if lt IE 7 ]> <span class="nt">"id"</span><span class="p">:</span> <span class="s2">"BRL"</span>
```

Comment: Então, você esta passando  Content-Type ?

Comment: Modifique sua pergunta, adicionando se possível pelo menos uma parte do código da chamada da sua função rest do Delphi.

Comment: Bom dia, O código utilizado é o seguinte:

Comment: Bom dia,
O código utilizado é o seginte:
 RESTClient.Accept := 'application/json';
 RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/currencies?id=BRL';
  RESTClient.AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8';
  RESTClient.ContentType := 'application/json';
 RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;  
 RESTRequest.Execute;
 Deveria retornar 
 { "id": "BRL",
    "symbol": "R$",
    "description": "Real",
    "decimal_places": 2}
Retorna
<!DOCTYPE html><!--if lt IE 7 ]>
  <span class="nt">"id"</span><span class="p">:</span> <span class="s2">"BRL"</span>... 
Utilizo o Delphi XE5.
Grato.

Comment: @WANDARLEIMICHELON edite a pergunta, não coloque seu código nos comentários, pois não conseguimos  te ajudar assim ;/

Answer (score 2):

A melhor opção quando a API REST não ajuda é utilizar a velha Indy.
Primeiramente copiamos a parte inicial onde deveria vir o json, depois resta apenas limpar a String

```
var
  vTemp : String;
begin
  vTemp := IdHTTP1.GET('https://api.mercadolibre.com/currencies/BRL');

  vTemp := Copy(vTemp, Pos('{', vTemp) + 1, Length(vTemp));
  vTemp := Copy(vTemp, 1, Pos('}', vTemp) - 1);

  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, '<span class="collapsible">', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, '<span class="nt">', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, '<span class="mi">', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, '<span class="p">', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, '<span class="s2">', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, '</span>', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, #$A, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  vTemp := StringReplace(vTemp, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  ShowMessage(vTemp);
```

Eu já utilizo esta mesma estrutura de substituição para outra parte da mesma Api.

Obs: A API que ele esta usando não retorna um JSON (Diretamente para Delphi), retorna um resultado para exibição no navegador. Funcional eu mostraria se a API oferecesse suporte para tal. Antigamente ela oferecia, hoje não mais! Na [documentação](http://developers.mercadolibre.com/) Oficial ela oferece alguns Sdks para outras plataformas.

Comment: Creio que o ideal aqui seria mostrar uma forma funcional de utilizar a REST, embora a alternativa seja válida.

Comment: A API que ele esta usando não retorna um JSON, retorna um resultado para exibição no navegador. Funcional eu mostraria se a API oferecesse suporte para tal. Antigamente ela oferecia, hoje não mais!

Comment: Legal, Júnior! Pode adicionar essa informação à resposta, por favor? Aí já concedo a recompensa! :)

Answer (score 1):

O que faltou:

```
RESTRequest.Accept        := 'application/json';
```

O mesmo pra quando for usar o Indy:

```
xIdHttp.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
```

Comment: Mas no código de exemplo que ele postou, já tem esta linha